# AdSense ad sliding up in front of my header

Tags: css, z-index, adsense

I'm sure there's an easy fix. If you look at http://www.guitarforbeginners.com/ and scroll the page you'll see that my adsense banner slides up over me header. The header is 'position:fixed' in CSS. I tried putting a z-index into the CSS but that made the whole thing weird.

Thanks,

Kirk

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` will help, but first... your HTML needs some serious help. HTML issues may be contributing to your layout issues. There are elements open all over the place, scripts and CSS where they shouldn't be (they should often be in the `<head></head>`, though not always necessarily so...).

But besides that, the following CSS should help your issue at hand. Giving  `.header_site` a very high `z-index` will stack or position it higher:

```
.header_site {
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, leftside. I actually fixed it myself by giving it a z-index of 1. Yes, I know my html is all over the place. I've been scrambling to get the site back up after it was hacked. I will get in there and try to clean it up.